# AWK replace some special new line to one line

Tags: sed, awk, perl

i have some log like this:

```
2023-11-15T08:59:28.000000+00:00 database-1 # Time: 231115  8:59:28
# User@Host: rdsadmin[rdsadmin] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 3  Schema:   QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.000123  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 49
SET timestamp=1700038768;
SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=60 FOR SELECT 1;
```

can you help me to change out put using awk or somthing like that to:

```
2023-11-15T08:59:28.000000+00:00 database-1 # Time: 231115  8:59:28 # User@Host: rdsadmin[rdsadmin] @ localhost [] # Thread_id: 3  Schema:   QC_hit: No # Query_time: 0.000123  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0 # Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 49
SET timestamp=1700038768;
SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=60 FOR SELECT 1;
```

Note: all line start with # charater will show in one line

Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the job using Perl:

```perl
perl -0777 -ape 's/\R(?=#)/ /g' file
2023-11-15T08:59:28.000000+00:00 database-1 # Time: 231115  8:59:28 # User@Host: rdsadmin[rdsadmin] @ localhost [] # Thread_id: 3  Schema:   QC_hit: No # Query_time: 0.000123  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0 # Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 49
SET timestamp=1700038768;
SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=60 FOR SELECT 1;
```

Where:

```
-0777                   # option that makes the file to be considered as a one line file
-ape                    # loop, print and execute
's/\R(?=#)/ /g'         # substitute any linebreak followed by "#" with a space
file                    # file to be processed
```